# Unable to prevent a link to redirect after successful ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have this HTML code

```
<div class="pull-right" id="pagination">
    <ul class="pagination">
        <li><a href="/filter/sector/c2VjXzE?page=1">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="/filter/sector/c2VjXzE?page=2">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="/filter/sector/c2VjXzE?page=3">3</a></li>
        <li><a href="/filter/sector/c2VjXzE?page=4">4</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and I am able to replace the code above anytime an ajax call is successful as shown in the snippet below

```js
$("#pagination").find("ul a").on('click', function(e) {
  alert('Link has been clicked');
  e.preventDefault();
});

function update() {
  $.ajax({
    dataType: 'json',
    url: url,
    data: {
      page: page_to_visit
    }
  }).done(function(json) {
    var totalPage = json.total;

    var pagination_links = '<ul class="pagination">';

    var i = 1;
    while (i <= totalPage) {
      pagination_links = pagination_links + '<li><a href="' + url + '?page=' + i + '">' + i + '</a></li>';
      i++;
    }

    pagination_links = pagination_links + '</ul>';

    $("#pagination").html(pagination_links);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pull-right" id="pagination">
    <ul class="pagination">
        <li><a href="/filter/sector/c2VjXzE?page=1">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="/filter/sector/c2VjXzE?page=2">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="/filter/sector/c2VjXzE?page=3">3</a></li>
        <li><a href="/filter/sector/c2VjXzE?page=4">4</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

But the problem I am facing is that, before the ajax call, when I click on the links in the HTML code, I get what is expected. But after making the ajax call, the links redirect me to another page instead of staying on the page and displaying the alert.

kindly help me solve this problem.

Comment: To explain why this is happening. When you remove elements in the DOM all events bound to them will be destroyed. Even if you replace them with the exact same element again in the exact same location in the DOM. When adding elements dynamically to the DOM you will either need to re-bind the events each time or using delegate event bindings by targeting the elements through a static traversable element, such as a static parent. You can do the latter using [**jquery on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) which supports Delegated events.

Comment: I've added your comment to my answer @Fran. couldn't put it any better myself, hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change your `on` binding:

```
$("#pagination").on('click','ul a',function(e) {
 ....
});
```

So you bind the event to the static element `"#pagination"` but filter for events in `"ul a"` by specifying a [selector](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

> A selector string to filter the descendants of the selected elements
>   that trigger the event. If the selector is null or omitted, the event
>   is always triggered when it reaches the selected element.

This allows the event to fire even though the elements change, because the event  is bound to something that doesn't change, i.e. `"#pagination"`.

To quote frans comment/good explanation of **why** this is happening:

> When you remove elements in the DOM all events bound to them will be
>   destroyed. Even if you replace them with the exact same element again
>   in the exact same location in the DOM.

Comment: This will allow dynamically created elements to still have an event